# How could I make this PHP $_POST more secure? -Or is it secure already?

Tags: php, mysql, security

On most my $_post data inputted on my site I use the following php:

```
$example = $_POST['textfield'];
$example = strip_tags($example);
$example = mysql_real_escape_string($example);
```

And then I would interact with the MySQL database...

Is this 'secure' / 'safe'?

Any major exploits to the above code?

-How could I make it secure?

Thanks alot.

Comment: I believe it's considered more secure to do prepared statements using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Wow @Jared Farrish, I use to do straight PHP->MySQL calls the 'old school' way, but now after you pointed out PDO and I looked into it a bit, it looks quite awesome. Next project I start, I'm using this!

Comment: PDO's a good suggestion, but not necessarily the only game in town. A key principle to extract from the suggestion: Security can't be something you have to remember to do EVERY TIME you write a db interaction (or filter user input for other uses, or whatever). Build your app in such a way that validation/cleansing is automatic and uses the same code every time.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend getting yourself a simple, simple function that uses PDO and parameterizing of queries by default behind the scenes.

Here are sample use cases for query functions that use PDO in the background that I use all the time:

```
$iterable_resultset = query('select * from users where email = :email and username ~* :username or user_id = :user_id', array(':email'=>$email, ':username'=>$username, ':user_id'=>(int)$user_id));
// Results a resultset that is able to be foreached over.

$multidimensional_array = query_array('select * from users where email = :email and username ~* :username or user_id = :user_id', array(':email'=>$email, ':username'=>$username, ':user_id'=>(int)$user_id));
// Results in a multidimensional array with each subarray corresponding to a database row, or null.


$row_of_data = query_row('select * from users limit 1');
//Results in a single dimensional array or null.

$item = query_item("select max(score) from players where username ~* :username", array(':username'=>$username));
// Returns a single piece of information, or null.
```

There's a lot of advantage from a refactoring viewpoint to having simple function-based parameterizing of sql queries.  PDO is often verbose, and sometimes when you're securing bad code you need simple, terse functions to fit in the place of old `mysql_query()` calls and the like.

In your specific case, I think that you are making the mistake of escaping before it's time, which can often introduce weird bugs.

```
$untrusted_input = @$_REQUEST['password'];
```

is all that you should do when getting the input.  Don't strip tags, don't do anything until it comes time to **-use-** that untrusted input in sql or in html:

- In the sql, parameterize it while using the sql, filter/modify the data based on the circumstances.
- When outputting to html, escape it then, e.g. via `.htmlentities($example).` or using a templating engine.

Here's an example of your code turning a non-existent get/post variable (that would normally result in `null`) into an empty string, for just the first of many subtle things that happen when you escape too early: http://ideone.com/r7bSr

In general, when you're first getting used to the security issues that php can throw your way, I really recommend using a template engine (e.g. smarty) to help you keep your business logic and your display templates separate.  A lot of people will argue about whether you need a templating engine with php because php is a templateable system already.  Engine or not doesn't matter, but a template-based approach to separate your manipulation logic from your display logic is very necessary, which most programmers would probably agree on.  And personally, I found it easier to learn how that separation benefits php when I was first starting out by just learning how a templating engine does things, before I could understand how to apply those principles to native php without a templating engine.

TL;DR; - Set up a templating engine, it'll get you using best practices faster.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like there are any security issues with your code. But like grossvogel said, you shouldn't try to implement security by constantly writing that function every time you have a query, because maybe you'll forget. What I would recommend is that you write a helper function that automatically escapes the input for you. That or you could use prepared statements.

Answer (score -1):

Apart from what has already been mentioned, a crucial part you're missing is a `magic_quotes` check and taking according action, this means **reversing** all its effects. (unless you do that at the beginning after your script starts).

If enabled, magic_quotes will escape all quotes with a backslash, and each backslash with a backslash.

Read more about `magic_quotes` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Comment: This is a bad idea for a lot of reasons. The first one is stated directly in the link you provided: "Warning
This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.". Other than that, `magic_quotes` isn't secure at all.

Comment: @PiZzL3: I didn't suggest the feature. I suggested being *aware* of it. That's why you need to reverse its effects! "taking according action" Maybe I should have made it more clear.

Comment: He's not even using it in his code, so why would that need reversing? You should just say to never use `magic_quotes` and never use `mysql_real_escape_string` (both methods have publicly known flaws and can easily be exploited, even when used together(which can cause more problems and exploits to appear that were previously do-able by themselves)). He should use `PDO` or other methods of using prepared statements, along with very specific custom filtering depending on each data type he's working with (examples: numbers, letters a-z only, etc..).

Comment: "He's not even using it in his code" Apparently you don't know what it is. I have never seen anybody using `magic_quotes` in his code... You cannot always control whether `magic_quotes` is enabled or not. That's why your script has to *adapt* and reverse everything `magic_quotes` has done in case it is enabled. Using PDOs does not save you from enabled `magic_quotes`.

Comment: @PiZzL3: See, someone in exactly this situation, only a few minutes ago. An ignorant already posted a very rude answer telling him to just disable magic_quotes and use PDO...: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661406/best-method-of-disabling-php-magic-quotes-without-php-ini-or-htaccess